# Good Practice? Eval function from JSON sent over WebSockets

Tags: json, node.js, websocket

I am considering the following architecture.  A client connected to a server via websockets send a JSON package to the server.  Inside of the JSON besides other data there is "action":"somefunction();".  The server will then parse the JSON and if the action is not empty then it will eval and thus run that command.

The alternative to this would be to simply put a string "somefunction" in the action attribute and have a switch statement on the server to run the appropriate code.

Thoughts or other possibilities?

Comment: ***YES***, using `eval()` on code you get from the clientside is always good practice, and you should always do this to make sure your users have full access to everything on your server and then some.

Comment: Simple example ```"action": "process.exit()"```. Use the router pattern to workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe does not prevent a hostile client from sending arbitrary code to be executed. **It is a security hole.**

If you want to have client code trigger some functions on the server, then pass some data that your server will parse and check to make sure that only the appropriate code is executed. It could be a JSON structure like this that the client sends:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "arguments": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

When the server receives it and parses it with `JSON.parse`, it verifies that `name` is a valid value and invokes the corresponding function. The functions could be in a structure like this

```
var dispatch = {
    foo: function (a, b, c) { },
    bar: function (a) { }
    // etc...
}
```

And once the JSON data is parsed and stored into a variable named `data` (for instance), the invocation could be:

```
dispatch[data.name].apply(undefined, data.arguments)
```

If needed return data could also be returned to the client as a JSON structure.

Answer (score -1):

I tend to use `window["function_name_as_string"](param1,param2);` if I am calling a function by name with dynamic data.